# Prove that when the denominator of a rational number is of the form $2^n * 5^m$ it is a terminating decimal

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion, rationality-testing

What is the proof for when the denominator of a rational number is of the form $2^n * 5^m$ it is a terminating decimal?

For example:
$7/8$, where $8$ is of the form $2^3 * 5^0$
Therefore, $7/8$ is a terminating decimal

But why does this work?

What is the proof?

Comment: Have you tried an induction? Try to do one over all rationals of the form $\frac{1}{2^k}$ and adterwards, for some fixed $k$ over all rationals of the form $\frac{1}{2^k\cdot 5^l}$.

Comment: $2^n \cdot 5^m \mid 10^{\max(n,m)}$

Comment: $$\frac{k}{2^n\cdot5^m}=\frac{k\cdot2^m\cdot5^n}{2^n\cdot2^m\cdot5^n\cdot5^m}=\frac{k\cdot2^m\cdot5^n}{10^{n+m}}$$